# How to obtain an envelope of my mas-spring damping curve?

Tags: signal-analysis

I have my program for mass spring system made with Euler method...and I can't menage to obtain envelope of the BLUE damping curve. Can you help me?

[image]

```
#****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
# Damped spring-mass oscillator
# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
from pylab import *
from scipy.signal import hilbert,chirp

g =  0          #grawitacja [m/s2] bez grawitacji 0
g = -9.80665       #grawitacja [m/s2] bez grawitacji 0
m = 0.4532      #masa ciężaru [kg]
k = 875.60      #sztywność [N/m]
# c = (2*m)*sqrt(k/m)
c = 0
c_kr = 2*sqrt(k*m)
c = 2*sqrt(k*m)
c = 5.0         #tlumienie [Ns/m]

omega=sqrt(k/m)
f=omega/(2*pi)
T=1/f
T=2*pi/omega
f1=1/T
gamma=c/c_kr
p=c/(2*m)

print('dekrement tłumienia',gamma,'  [s]')
print('tłumienie', c)
print('tłumienie krytyczne',c_kr)
print('omega czestosc własna',omega,'  [rad]')
print('czestotliwosc',f,'  [Hz=1/s]')
print('czestotliwosc',f1,'  [Hz=1/s]')
print('okres',T,'  [s]')
# print('e',e,'  [s]')

u_pocz=-0.0254  #ugięcie, przemieszczenie wstępne sprężyny [m]
u_pocz= 0.0     #ugięcie, przemieszczenie wstępne sprężyny [m]
v_pocz= 0.0     #prędkość w [m/s]
t_pocz= 0.0     #czas w [s]
env_pocz= 0.0   #czas w [s]

dt=0.001        #przyrost czasu [s]
t_kon=0.15      #czas końca obliczeń [s]
t_kon=1.00      #czas końca obliczeń [s]

print('czas',t_kon,'  [s]')

u=u_pocz        #przemieszczenie [m]
v=v_pocz        #prędkość w [m/s]
t=t_pocz        #czas w [s]
env=env_pocz    #czas w [s]

#To mogę policzyć bo wiem, ugięcie, wydłużenie sprężyny w [m] - a dlaczego tak ?
#bo k*u=G (siła ciężkości) czyli k*u=m*g dlatego u=m*g/k

# u_ugiecie_wlasne=m*g/k-u_pocz                 #ugięcie przemieszczenie własne w [m]
# a=-g-(k/m)*(u-u_ugiecie_wlasne)-c*v*abs(v)/m  #przyspieszenie pocztkowe w [m/s2] ale potrzebne to bedzie dopierow później
u_ugiecie_wlasne=m*(g)/k                        #ugięcie przemieszczenie własne w [m] bez LOAD_BODY
print('u_ugiecie_wlasne',u_ugiecie_wlasne,'  [s]')

przechowalnia_u=[]
przechowalnia_v=[]
przechowalnia_a=[]
przechowalnia_F=[]
przechowalnia_t=[]
przechowalnia_env=[]


# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
#                                                           Obliczenia zasadnicze
# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

while (t<t_kon):

    a=-g-(k*(u-u_ugiecie_wlasne)/m)-(c*v/m)+g   # dv/dt=a=(-g-k*(u+u_ugiecie_wlasne)/m-c*v/m) z LOAD_BODY czyli przyspieszenie ziemskie *g

    v=v+a*dt                                    # v=v+dt*dv/dt
    u=u+v*dt                                    # u=u+dt*du/dt
    F=(-g-(k*(u-u_ugiecie_wlasne)/m)-(c*v/m))*m                                     
    t=t+dt

    przechowalnia_u.append(u)
    przechowalnia_v.append(v)
    przechowalnia_a.append(a)
    przechowalnia_F.append(F)
    przechowalnia_t.append(t)
    przechowalnia_env.append(env)


# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
#                                                           Obliczenia zasadnicze
# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************



# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
#                                                                Grafika
# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

# coding: utf-8
from matplotlib.font_manager    import FontProperties
# okno = get_current_fig_manager()

def quit_figure(event):
    if event.key == 'escape':
       close(event.canvas.figure)
    if event.key == 'f10':
       savefig('0.png',dpi=150)

# rcParams.update({'font.size': 24})
rcParams['font.size'] = 24                      #set the value globally
rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2                  #set the value globally
rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
font = {'family':'ISOCPEUR','weight':'normal','color':'black'}
# font = {'family':'ISOCPEUR','weight':'normal','color':'black','size':10}
fig=figure(num=None,  frameon='False', figsize=(16, 7), facecolor='w')
# title('Identification of Johnson-Cook constitutive equations in terms of FEM simulation\n$\mathrm{Y=}$',font)
ylabel('Przemieszczenie [m]')
xlabel('Czas [s]')
plot(przechowalnia_t, przechowalnia_u, linewidth=4, color='b',label='u - przemieszczenie, [m]')
# plot(analytical_signal, linewidth=2, color='b',label='u - przemieszczenie, [m]')
# plot(amplitude_envelope, linewidth=4, color='r',label='u - przemieszczenie, [m]')

# plot(przechowalnia_t, przechowalnia_a, linewidth=4, color='r',label='a - przyspieszenie, [m/s$^2$]'')
# plot(przechowalnia_t, przechowalnia_v, linewidth=4, color='r',label='v - prędkość, [m/s2]')
# plot(przechowalnia_t, przechowalnia_F, linewidth=4, color='r',label='F - siła, [N]')
axvline(0,linestyle='--',linewidth=2,color='r')
axhline(0,linestyle='--',linewidth=2,color='r')
hlines(u_ugiecie_wlasne,t_pocz,t_kon,linestyle='-',linewidth=4,color='g',label='ugięcie własne w [m]')
legend(loc='upper right')

quit = gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', quit_figure)

show()

# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
#                                                                Grafika
# ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

I did it but I am afraid that I wonted something else - I wantef  logarithmic damping increment and I have to figure out how to draw from the elvelope the information about level of damping. Nevertheless - thank you.

[image]

Comment: so, this looks nice, but what have you tried so far? It's hard to really help you if we don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: Have you tried the hilbert envelope?

Comment: I have tried Hilbert envelope - it doesn't work :(

Comment: The programs works - ok. I just need the uper and down envelope. I don't know how to do it - ok. Then I looked for some aproximation in Python with "signa envelope" subject etc. In the Internet in most cases there was  Hilbert solution answer. Then I implemente to my program but it didn't work...Additionaly I didn't find any example of working Hilbert solution for real data...or if the solution seems good I don't see the data. My curve is just displacement in time function and when I put it to envelope = abs(hilbert(displacement)) and then plot (time, envelope) it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have numerically solved a second order differential equation and plotted its result. Now it seems to be a damped sinusoidal response of the type

$$y(t) = K e^{-\alpha t} \cos(\omega_0 t + \phi) $$

for some constants $\alpha$, $\omega_0$ and $K$. And you want to compute the damping parameter $\alpha$.

A crude approximation to $\alpha$ can be obtained by the following. Consider two points, one at an arbitrary time $t_0$ and the other one period later $t_0 + T_0$, on the curve. You don't know the period ? It can be approximately decuded by looking at two consecutive peaks of the oscillations. Note that those peaks are slightly misplaced due to being weigted by the exponential; nevertheless it will be ok for a crude approximation. Then the values at those two points will be $A_1$ and $A_2$; then it can be seen that

$$ \frac{ |A_1| }{|A_2| } = \frac{ K e^{-\alpha t_0} }{K e^{-\alpha (t_0 + T_0) }} = e^{\alpha T_0}  $$

Note that you have already measured the period $T_0$ in the first step; hence you can find the damping parameter $\alpha$ to be

$$ \alpha = \frac{1}{T_0} \ln ( |A_1| / |A_2| ) $$

If you want to estimate it more accuretely, you might consider using different estimators for it. A Kalman filter can also be designed to esitmate it, but that's a lot more complex.